# Password in GRANT to be same as password of the existing username

Tags: mysql, sql, passwords, sql-grant

Say there is an existing user `user1` with password `pwd1`.

Now if I run a `GRANT` command s.t.-

```
GRANT INSERT, DELETE ON database1.* TO 'user1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pwd2';
```

Should `pwd1` and `pwd2` be same.

Now If they can be different, can two `GRANT` commands for `user1` use different passwords???

In addition to that what is the significance of the following-

```
GRANT INSERT, DELETE ON database1.* TO 'user1'@'localhost'
```

Here there is no password specified. So in this case can `user1` connect to tha database server without specifying any password while the account of `user1` is already associated with a password???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL provides `GRANT ... IDENTIFIED BY ...` as a shortcut for creating a user.

The mysql user model specifies a user@host approach to user names, and each user account has a password, so no the second does not allow access without a password.